DB2 fetch first first x rows only
I want to fetch first x rows only by the column IDENTIFIER.
But when I join abbrev table, its get multiplicated the result, because each identifier could have more than one result.
How can I say, that the fetching first x rows only referencing to the identifier?
SELECT IDENTIFIER, ABBREV
FROM TABLE_A taba
JOIN ABBREV abbrev ON abbrev.tablea_IDENTIFIER = taba.IDENTIFIER
FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY

Table_A



Identifier




1


2



Table_abb



abbrev
tablea_identifier




'A'
1


'B'
1


'C'
1


'A'
2



Result should be



abbrev
IDENTIFIER




'A'
1


'B'
1


'C'
1


'A'
2




It's not a problem with FETCH FIRST, but with your join (logic). Add more details on both tables or fix it yourself :). Most joins have additional WHERE conditions and select only specific columns. It looks like you are creating a result table as product from both source tables.

Yes it should be a result table from two source tables. But I want to filter the fetch first rows on specific column like here identifier

FETCH FIRST gives you the rows from whatever the result table is. You have to utilize WHERE to filter down the rows and SELECT to pick only the columns you need.

How can I do it?

LIMIT-ing without ORDER-ing rarely makes sense.

The result you provided on your data can be obtained without the fetch first clause at all. Is this a typo, that the row with abbrev='C' is in the desired result?

An easy way to solve your issue is to run a query like this:
select a.id, a.a
from abbrev a
where a.id in (select id from id)

You only select the records from abbrev that have an ID in the other (identifier / table_a) table. You can add the FETCH FIRST clause to it. What you did is more of a cartesian product (look it up).

Above idea from @data_henrik is nice.
You can also solve your problem by counting numbers of rows, which are coming after inner join with your Identifier. Somethings like that, in your case, after inner of table abbrev with Identifier, it is giving 4 rows (which is like total count values)
db<>fiddle
WITH 
    A (Identifier) AS (VALUES 1, 2),
    B (abbrev, tablea_identifier) AS (VALUES 
        ('A', 1),
        ('B', 1),
        ('C', 1),
        ('A', 2)),
    C AS (SELECT count(tablea_identifier) AS count_value FROM B)


SELECT main_1.abbrev, main_1.tablea_identifier FROM (
SELECT B.*, C.* FROM B, C
INNER JOIN A ON A.Identifier = B.tablea_identifier
) AS main_1
WHERE count_value = 4

Output:

#|ABBREV|TABLEA_IDENTIFIER|
-+------+-----------------+
1|A     |                1|
2|B     |                1|
3|C     |                1|
4|A     |                2|




